# Getting return value from .vbs called from Windows CMD

Tags: vbscript, cmd, msgbox

I've got a CMD file that writes a MsgBox popup command to a VBScript file, then turns around and immediately executes it.  Originally it just used an "OK" button to dismiss the warning that user version was out of date.  I want to modify it to use the Yes/No/Cancel buttons to allow user automatic version update.

Here is the code that just causes the pop-up. I've tried a few different things to try to get the .vbs file to return a value, but am having issues getting the syntax right. Any suggestions?

```
@echo X=MsgBox("Your Version: %VER%" +vbCrLf+ "Recommended: %RVER%" +vbCrLf+ "Do you want to update the version?",vbYesNoCancel,"Warning Message"^) >%APPDATA%\temp_msg2.vbs

call %APPDATA%\temp_msg2.vbs
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
echo X=MsgBox("Your Version: %VER%" +vbCrLf+ "Recommended: %RVER%" +vbCrLf+ "Do you want to update the version?",vbYesNoCancel,"Warning Message"^) >U:\temp_msg2.vbs
>>U:\temp_msg2.vbs echo wscript.quit X

call u:\temp_msg2.vbs

ECHO %errorlevel%

GOTO :EOF
```

Showed 6 for Yes, 7 for No and 2 for Cancel/big red x for me.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript is just a language, with many different hosts and applications - not just shell-scripting, so setting the return-value of a script is the responsibility of the host, not the language. In this case the host is either `cscript` or `wscript` (for command-line and windowed hosts, respectively). Both hosts expose the `WScript` object which is where you specify the return code as an argument to the `Quit` method (note that VBScript doesn't use parenthesis on `void` (`Sub`) method calls:

```
WScript.Quit 123
```

If you want to return the value from `MsgBox` you can provide it directly:

```
WScript.Quit MsgBox( "Foobar" )
```

Your `.cmd` batch file will need to know the numeric value of `vbYes`, `vbNo`, and `vbCancel`.

...I suggest doing all of the scripting from within the VBScript file and avoiding the use of `.cmd`/`.bat` files completely, if you can, as VBScript is much more readable and powerful (though I prefer using the JScript language instead, but that's just me).

MSDN has a reference to all of the members of the `WScript` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31(v%3Dvs.84).aspx

Here's a page listing other objects and functionality available from within `wscript`/`cscript` (collectively: "Windows Script Host"): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7(v=vs.84).aspx